# How to create a site collection in visual studio with the help of excel

Tags: development, site-collection

I have been trying to create a site collection using visual studio using C# and I have almost created one. but I want to create a site collection by fetching the details from Excel sheet but I have no idea what is the code would be for it.

Can anyone help me out with the code for creating a site collection by fetching the data from excel sheet using C#?

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution!